# How to do FULL SCREEN WINDOW functionality while clicking the button in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I have created the login page for the user. If They click the submit button, the page will navigate to one component (test.component.ts,test.component.html,..).

I need to make that window in full screen mode. like, (video control full screen in html5).

```
submitLogin() {
  if (this.userName === 'Student' && this.passWord === 'student@123'){
    this.dashboard = true; 
  } else {
    alert('Incorrect Username or Password');
  }
}
```

I don't know how to achieve the full screen window functionality. Because,  i am new to Angular2. Can Anyone solve my problem ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will only be feasible for newer versions of browsers. From your question, I do analyze that, submitLogin() is called after clicking the button. So, after clicking the button, you can achieve full screen using the following approach.

```
   submitLogin() {
     this.toggleFullScreen();
     if(this.userName == "Student" && this.passWord == "student@123"){
      this.dashboard = true; 
     }
     else{
       alert("Incorrect Username or Password");
      }
   }

   toggleFullScreen() {
    let elem =  document.body; 
    let methodToBeInvoked = elem.requestFullscreen || 
     elem.webkitRequestFullScreen || elem['mozRequestFullscreen'] || 
     elem['msRequestFullscreen']; 
    if(methodToBeInvoked) methodToBeInvoked.call(elem);

}
```

You can go to the following link to read more. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode)

Updated: 
    ActiveXObject is available only on IE browser. So every other useragent will throw an error. 
    You can use the following code:

```
 toggleFullScreen() {
        let elem =  document.body; 
        let methodToBeInvoked = elem.requestFullscreen || 
         elem.webkitRequestFullScreen || elem['mozRequestFullscreen'] 
         || 
         elem['msRequestFullscreen']; 
        if(methodToBeInvoked) methodToBeInvoked.call(elem);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But, Where do i to declare this requestFullScreen ? and ActiveXObject ?. It displays red color underline on my code.

Comment: You can use them like. elem['requestFullScreen']  and window['ActiveXObject']. If this doesn't resolve the issue, please forward me the error message. If it does, please mark my answer as best answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: If this worked for me, I would definitely point your answer to the best answer.

let obj = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");


what i have to do in this line? it displays the 
Cannot find name 'ActiveXObject' in this particular line.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works for me.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem again with this. Can you help me again??

Comment: Is anyone getting this to work on Firefox? It only works on chrome for me.

Comment: @skydev  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834858/full-screen-window-code-working-in-chrome-not-working-in-firefox]

Answer (score 1):

Check this library [fscreen](https://github.com/rafrex/fscreen) you wont have to worry about vendor prefixes, code is way cleaner, i did it for an angular app and this is the code i wrote:

```
hasFullscreenSupport: boolean = fscreen.fullscreenEnabled;
isFullscreen: boolean;

constructor() {
  if (this.hasFullscreenSupport) {
    fscreen.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', () => {
      this.isFullscreen = (fscreen.fullscreenElement !== null);
    }, false);
  }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.hasFullscreenSupport) {
    fscreen.removeEventListener('fullscreenchange');
  }
}

toggleFullscreen() {
  if (this.hasFullscreenSupport && !this.isFullscreen) {
    const elem = document.body;
    fscreen.requestFullscreen(elem);
  } else {
    fscreen.exitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Comment: My experience with this is the fscreen.removeEventListener method has to have the same parameters as the related addEventListener method.