# FULL SCREEN WINDOW code working in Chrome, Not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, fullscreen

Already i have posted my question for full screen and i got the solution,
[How to do FULL SCREEN WINDOW functionality while clicking the button in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250551/how-to-do-full-screen-window-functionality-while-clicking-the-button-in-angular).

This solution is working fine for **Chrome** browser. But, Full screen window is not working In **Firefox** browsers

Here is my code:

```
<button (click)="fullscreen()">Click</button>

fullscreen()
{
   let elem =  document.body; 
   let methodToBeInvoked = elem.requestFullscreen || 
   elem.webkitRequestFullScreen || elem['mozRequestFullscreen'] 
   || elem['msRequestFullscreen']; 

   if(methodToBeInvoked) methodToBeInvoked.call(elem);
}
```

Do I have to add something in this code for Firefox browser?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because of typo. Change `elem['mozRequestFullscreen']` to `elem['mozRequestFullScreen']` and you 'll be fine.

You can find working version [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8vd3u4o7/4/).